# Dropdown.SelectedItem.Text isnt setting value properly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, selecteditem, dropdown

I have the following dropdown

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlCardStatus" runat="server" Width="150px">
  <asp:ListItem Value="E0" Text="Active" ></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="E1" Text="Block"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

My dropdown default selected text always remains `Active` even when I get `Block` in my dataset.

I guess I'm setting it wrong
Here's the code of setting value recieved from dataset

```
ddlCardStatus.SelectedItem.Text = ddlCardStatus.Items.FindByValue(
     IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Status")), 0, 
                 ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Status"))).Value
```

**EDITED** This is the part of the stored procedure that is selecting `Status`

```
Select ID,case status when 'E0' then 'Active' when 'E1' then 'Block' end as 'Status' from temp
```

Comment: If it is by **Text** then replace **FindByValue(** with **FindByText(**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the value directly if you have one, rather then text:-

```
ddlCardStatus.SelectedValue = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Status").Value
```

You can check for Null, but setting it to `0` doesn't makes sense as you don't have any such ListItem in your dropdown.

**Update:**

Since you are passing text from DB, you can either find that text in the dropdown collection and select it:-

```
String cardStatus = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Status")
ddlCardStatus.Items.FindByText(cardStatus).Selected = True
```

Or you can find the value from dropdown collection and set the selected value:-

```
String cardStatus = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Status")
ddlCardStatus.SelectedValue = ddItems.Items.FindByText(cardStatus).Value
```

Comment: but Value attribute set to either `E0` or `E1`. I am getting `Active` or `Block` i.e Text so I used `ddlCardStatus.SelectedItem.Text`

Comment: I am getting either `Active` or `Block`. I am NOT getting `E0` or `E1`.

Comment: How do I write query?

Comment: The data is returned from a stored procedure